# Adding optional table to appropriate foreign key column

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, match, option-type

I'm a bit new to SQL and databases, and thought I'd make an employee database to improve my knowledge, but I'm having trouble with a FK matching dilemma.

I have two tables `salaries` and `benefits`.

`salaries` has a FK column `salaries.benefits` referencing `benefits.benefitID`.

In this particular use case, I have the FK as `nullable` / "optional" because not all employees will have benefits.

Where I'm having trouble: How do we add the appropriate `benefitID` to the `salaries.benefits` column, when the employee *does* have benefits?

My first assumption is to create the appropriate benefits row first, then get the `benefits.benefitID` and insert it into the appropriate `salaries.benefits` column, but I'm not sure how to match the appropriate row ID's.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

suppose in benefits table you have benefit_type/id column where based on the type/id you have the benefits associated. Then for a particular employee, you can insert employee.salary.benefit=type/id.

Comment: Ah! I see, like some kind of unique identifier in a benefit row, such that I can filter for that particular value?

Comment: yeah, that's right